# How to split the following data into separate rows using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get the values in the 'Output' column split into separate rows:

| Category | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Car | Doc, writeback |
| Car | Trace, dataview |

This needs to be:

| Category | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Car | Doc |
| Car | Trace |
| Car | writeback |
| Car | dataview |

I've tried:
`new_df = auto_test_file.DataFrame(auto_test_file.Output.str.split('|').tolist(), index=auto_test_file.Region).stack()`

but this gives the error:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Category': ["Car", "Car"], 'Output': ["Doc, writeback", "Trace, dataview"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_splitted = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
for i in range(len(df)):
    outputs = df['Output'][i].split(',')
    for j in outputs:
        df_splitted.loc[len(df_splitted)] = [df['Category'][i], j]
print(df_splitted)
```